# log4net mapping custom data to field in database

Tags: c#, database, log4net, categories

I am migrating from Enterprise Library, and its Write() api lets us specify things like Category, Severity, Title, and Priority.

For this specific example, I'd like to log, into a database field, a user supplied value for category. e.g. consider an online shopping cart, I want to put categories like [Cameras], [Laptops], [Routers], [Account], [Orders], [Shipping], etc.

I know that log4net has a properties field and we are doing that already in our config to map to the database:

```
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@MachineName" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
```

I want my Api to look something like this:

```
public class LogService
{
   public LogService() 
   {
      _log = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
   }

   public void WriteDebug(string message, string category)
   {
     _log.Debug(message);
   }
}
```

Could I do this, would it be safe? or is there another way?

> ```
> public void WriteDebug(string message, string category)
> {
>     ThreadContext.Properties["Category"] = category
>     _log.Debug(message);
>     ThreadContext.Properties["Category"] = "";
> }
> ```

We do have a lot of async code in our application code base... so I'm worried that this is not thread safe at all.

Answer (score 1):

[log4net.ThreadContext](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.ThreadContext.html) **is safe for multithreaded operations** and provides a location for thread specific information to be stored. You can also specify thread id/name, in your PatternLayout for better insight. In that same layout provide all needed properties, just as you specified host name. 
If you want to log to a database use [AdoNetAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html).